# jupyter lab output multiline python comments

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Jupyter lab output to cell multiline python comments, this not happend with one line comment.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Jupyterlab Version 3.4.4

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a semicolon (`;`) after the closing `"""` to suppress the output, e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a string in triple quotations is not a comment. This is a `docstring` and not a comment.

You can read more here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/triple-quotes-in-python/

The easiest way to have multi-line comments in Jupyter is to highlight everything you want to comment and then press `Ctrl` and `/` at the same time. This will toggle comments on/off and you can use it on a single line or on numerous lines at once. This also works in numerous IDEs such as PyCharm and VSCode.

---

Some other resources:

https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/

https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/contributing/ipython-dev-guide/documenting_ipython.html